# node: dns.resolve can not get correct ip after calling dns.setServers

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm writing a program to resolve ip address with specific dns server, but it seems that `.setServers` method is not working...

```js
const dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers(['208.67.222.222', '208.67.220.220']);
console.log(dns.getServers());
dns.resolve('littlee.github.io', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res);
});
```

terminal logs:

```
[ '208.67.222.222', '208.67.220.220' ]
null [ '127.0.0.1' ]
```

the expected result should be: `185.199.108.153`

Comment: The use of 127.0.0.1 indicates to me that the address probably isn't being provided by a DNS server but rather the system's hosts file. This however doesn't align with the apparent fact that you're able to ping the address using the command line. Unless there's something that I'm missing. Is it on a different system or perhaps you changed the hosts file since doing the command-line ping? I'm leaning towards a hosts file entry being the culprit though.

Comment: @JonathanGray you are right, I notice that I've changed my hosts file. Is there some public restful api to for dns resolve, if I can not get the correct ip address by setting system dns?

Comment: As long as the hostname you're trying to resolve doesn't exist within the hosts file it should use the servers you specify. If you want to keep such entries in your hosts file without interfering with your app you can probably give your app a dedicated hosts file of its own by running it inside of a docker container.